# How to display a JSON file in a TextView

Tags: android, json

I'm very new to Android and having a lot of trouble understanding JSON. I have a separate JSON file with my values written out but no idea how to actually display those strings in an Android app.

Any comprehensive tutorials or basic-level explanations are very welcome. Thanks!

Comment: post your json file data for a small explation

Comment: Read the file. Make a `String`. Parse the JSON with GSON - https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Comment: @HyperPhrenic Have you got some idea about JSON now ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all try to understand [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) also. It allows the user to perform a `long background` operations and to show the results back to the user in the MainUI Thread. You can perform JSON parsing and  get values which is stored inside the `JSON file` via AsyncTask.

[JSON](http://www.json.org/) is very light, easy to understand and it's the best alternative to `XML`. To parse your JSON file you need to know about `JSONArray` and `JSONObject`. In a JSON file , square bracket `[` represents a JSON array and curly braces `{` represent the JSON objects. JSON is structured with `Key and Value pairs`. Get your string values with `getString("key");`and then just display it into `TextView`

**JSONArray** - It contains many `JSON Objects`.

**JSONObjects** - It contains `key` and `value` pairs.

1. **[** -> `It represents the JSON Array`
2. **{** -> `It represents the JSON Object`

Two methods `getJSONArray()` and `getJSONObject()` are mainly used in the JSON to represent the `json node`.

Get your `JSON Array` node.

```
JSONArray booksArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("books");
```

**JSON Code :**

```
 {
   "books": [                            //JSON array

      {                                  //represents JSON Object
         "id":"440",                     //Key and Value pair
         "edition": "Fourth",
         "language": "Java",
      },

      {
         "id":"407",
         "edition": "second",
         "language": "Python",

      }

   ]
}
```

Above code has one JSON Object(books) and one JSON Array it holds two json objects. See [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) for `JSON Parsing` in Android.

You can also `upload` your JSON file for free [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and view your JSON file as tree structure with [JsonViewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)

**NOTICE** : `Comments` are not officially supported in JSON. So I just added comments like in JAVA.